# Boolean in OracleDbType

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, stored-procedures

what is Oracle equivalent for Boolean? I have this function where I need to pass onlineFiling to a stored procedure as bool but apparently Oracle don't have Boolean in its OracleDbType. How do I do this? thanks

```
public List<MModel> GetReportData(DateTime startDateTime, DateTime endDateTime, bool onlineFiling)
        {
            var managementModel = new List<ManagementModel>();
            var oracCmd = new OracCommand(1);
            oracCmd.AddInParameter(OracleDbType.Date, "I_STARTDATE", startDateTime));
            oracCmd.AddInParameter(OracleDbType.Date, "I_ENDDATE", endDateTime));
            oracCmd.AddInParameter(OracleDbType.???, "I_ONLINE", onlineFiling));
//rest of code here
```

Comment: You'll have to either change your function specification to accept a character or number flag instead; or add a wrapper function that translates a character/number to boolean and calls your original function. [There is no native type](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleDbTypeEnumerationType.htm), even though you're calling PL/SQL not [SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3726758/266304).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the Oracle Data Provider documentation at [Data Provider for .NET Developer's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleDbTypeEnumerationType.htm). ODP does not seem to support boolean.

One option could be to use `Char` instead or `Number` with 1/0.

Also you should have a look at following SO posts:

["Boolean" parameter for Oracle stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079662/boolean-parameter-for-oracle-stored-procedure)

[How to pass boolean parameter to Oracle procedure C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27919012/how-to-pass-boolean-parameter-to-oracle-procedure-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the stored procedure that you are calling, but it's commonly used the Binary type of ORACLE parameters.

```
public List<MModel> GetReportData(DateTime startDateTime, DateTime endDateTime, bool onlineFiling)
{
    var managementModel = new List<ManagementModel>();

    var oracCmd = new OracCommand(1);
    oracCmd.AddInParameter(OracleDbType.Date, "I_STARTDATE", startDateTime));
    oracCmd.AddInParameter(OracleDbType.Date, "I_ENDDATE", endDateTime));
    oracCmd.AddInParameter(OracleDbType.BinaryDouble, "I_ONLINE", onlineFiling));

    //rest of code here
```

But you have to make sure which type is being returned and the convert the result to the right type.