# "ORA-03115: unsupported network datatype or representation" when trying to execute stored procedure with .NET Core

Tags: oracle, asp.net-core, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I am using an Oracle 11g database. When I try to execute a stored procedure with .NET Core and `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core`, I get this exception:

> ORA-03115: unsupported network datatype or representation" from source "Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver

This is my C# code:

```
using (OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("procedureName", conn))
{
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_system", OracleDbType.Varchar2, "SystemName", ParameterDirection.Input));
    command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_filename", OracleDbType.Varchar2, "fileName.xml", ParameterDirection.Input));
    command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_document", OracleDbType.Clob, "document", ParameterDirection.Input));

    OracleParameter errorParameter = new OracleParameter("p_error", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Output);
    command.Parameters.Add(errorParameter);

    command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_DumpDebugMsgs", OracleDbType.Boolean, true, ParameterDirection.Input));

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

And this is the stored procedure I want to execute:

```
procedure procedureName(
    p_system IN VARCHAR2,
    p_filename IN VARCHAR2,
    p_document IN CLOB,
    p_error OUT NUMBER,
    p_DumpDebugMsgs IN BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE
)
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Just to check: can you try your sample and remove the CLOB parameter in both the stored procedure and in your C# code? The problem can be the CLOB implementation.

Comment: Create another procedure just for the test (you can just put `null;` in the body). IE : ```create or replace procedure procedureNameTest(p_system IN VARCHAR2, p_filename IN VARCHAR2, p_error OUT NUMBER, p_DumpDebugMsgs IN BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE ) as  BEGIN  NULL; END; /``` then you can drop it `DROP PROCEDURE procedureNameTest;`

Comment: The CLOB implementation does not seem to be the problem. Because I got the same exception if I call the stored procedure without the CLOB parameter.

Comment: ok bad guess :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem! The boolean parameter `p_DumpDebugMsgs` caused the exception. ODP does not seem to support boolean parameters as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39152403/boolean-in-oracledbtype/39152560#39152560).

Because the parameter `p_DumpDebugMsgs` has a default value, I ended up not passing a value for this parameter.

Comment: Great! please mark you answer as "accepted answer" for futur SO users!