# Calling a stored procedure with a boolean parameter

Tags: mule

I have a task for a `Mule` flow to call an `Oracle` database stored procedure. This procedure has a number of parameters, which are all being passed successfully except the a `boolean` value. I'm getting the following error, no matter what I try:

> java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type

From a bit of research it's my understanding that `boolean` values are not supported in the `Oracle JDBC` library and cannot be passed to `PL/SQL` stored procedures. If this is true, how would one work around this problem in `Mule`, or would the stored procedure itself have to be changed?

Many thanks

Comment: here is the answer to your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079662/boolean-parameter-for-oracle-stored-procedure

Answer (score 0):

try using BIT type

Reference: https://github.com/mulesoft/mulesoft-docs/blob/master/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/database-connector-reference.adoc

Answer (score 0):

Use parameterized query and while adding parameter select parameter type as BOOLEAN from drop down.